# How to disable an href given a condition?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a link that I need to disable depending on the permission a user has. 
Below is the htmn for the link:

```
<div ng-repeat="userAgreement in journalist.userAgreements">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="attachment in userAgreement.attachments">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="color: #2a98d4">
            <ul style="margin-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 1.5em;">
                <li class="fa fa-check-circle" style="font-size: 1.1em; margin: 3px;">
                    <a target="_blank" href="{{attachment.url}}" ng-click="agreementPermission($event)" class="cursor-pointer" style="font-family: FranklinITCProLight">{{getAttachmentName(userAgreement.agreement, attachment)}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-show="!hasAttachments">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="color: #2a98d4">
        <ln code="journalist.completed.documents.empty" args=""></ln>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

(The `ng-click` doesn't work)

Here is the js directive for that file:

```
define(["app"], function (app) {
    return app.directive('completedAgreements',[
        function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: '/directives/completed-agreements.html',
                link: function ($scope, elm, attrs) {
                    $scope.hasAttachments = false;
                    $scope.getAttachmentName = function(agreement, attachment) {
                        $scope.hasAttachments = true;
                        if(attachment.templateId) {
                            return attachment.name;
                        } else {
                            if(agreement.type == 'DIRECT_DEPOSIT') {
                                return "Payment Documents"
                            } else {
                                var specialization = agreement.specialisation.toLowerCase();
                                return specialization.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + specialization.slice(1) + " Agreement";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    ])
});
```

The function that is within the ng-click:

```
$scope.agreementPermission = function(e) {
            if (!SecurityService.canViewAgreements()) {
                showError($uibModal, "You do not have permission to access this attachment. Please contact an administrator.", null, null, null, null, "Access Denied");
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        };
```

As I am new to javascript, I am not sure if this function is in the correct place.  It is an another controller file, should it be in the js directive for the html? So basically, when a user without permission clicks the link, the showError box will be triggered, if they do have permission, then the page will redirect to the link. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! let me know if I should provide further information!:-)

Comment: I don't know the specifics of Angular myself. But the first things I would try is adding logging to each step of what should be happening. So, in "link," and "agreementPermission," and within the if statement that does `e.preventDefault()`. This will help you figure out which part isn't working or isn't being run.

Comment: Is the href value taking the user to another page, outside of the angular app, or is it just a route within the application? I can think of a few ideas, depending on the use case here.

Comment: its just an agreement document, im assuming its within the application.

Answer (score 4):

```css
a.disable{
    pointer-events: none; 
}
```

```html
<!--You can add css class to disable the link (anchor), example: -->
<a ng-class="{'disable': isAvailable(product.id)}">see product</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

rewrite the tags `<a>` tag to `<a disabled>`

see
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_attributes.asp

it should be editable through javascript as an object as well.
look for something like:

```
object = document.getElementById("MyElem");
object.disabled = true;
```

or

```
object.active = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="onClickFunc(event, {{ element.id or class }})"

function onClickFunc(event, somedata) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Stops the default behavior
    // ...
}
```

// event.preventDefault(); stops the default behavior of the link.

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: Sure, event.preventDefault(); stops the default behavior of the link which was added in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use button instead of link. Give it CSS class="btn btn-link"(Bootstrap).
Call the function agreementPermission on ng-click.

Comment: Did not get you @gcampbell

Comment: Accessibility. Things like screen readers treat buttons and links differently.

Comment: How would that be an issue?

Comment: It's a problem if you want to support things like screen readers.